# I want to delay the animation on my div so that they could appear one after the other, how can i do that?

Tags: html, angular, css

I have a list offers made by a user which I want to display using the slideInLeft animation I've found online in this [repo](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css)/[the animations in action](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) but I want to make it that each offers arrives 100ms after the first one. How can I do that?

My code would look something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let offer of offers">
      <div class="animated infinite slideInLeft delay-2s">offer data</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you read the docs? 
"It's possible to change the duration of your animations, add a delay or change the number of times that it plays"

Using your own css rule with `animation-delay: 100ms`. You can stagger the items delay by using javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Is there a way to do so in angular?

Comment: Not a clue. Perhaps consider editing your question to include that you want it in angular, then the right people can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let offer of offers; let i= index;">
  <div class=`animated infinite slideInLeft delay-${i}`>offer data</div>
</div>
```

take each offer index and add it to class  the number to delay- class!
now u can add for each class a delay!